# Strange StackOverflow on Microsoft DI

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am tearing my hair out trying to figure out why the system is having StackOverflow. Especially hard since the below line is part of Microsoft's Dependency Injection.

```
internal object GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
{
    if (_disposed)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException(); --> This line is where it Stack Overflowed
    }

    var realizedService = RealizedServices.GetOrAdd(serviceType, _createServiceAccessor);
    _callback?.OnResolve(serviceType, serviceProviderEngineScope);
    return realizedService.Invoke(serviceProviderEngineScope);
}
```

Since the code is not mine, I can't even debug it.

I have tried my best to sort out all the dependencies to see if there is a circular one, and there isn't.

Since the StackOverflow is always on the Throw Exception I would think it isn't caused by circular DI.

Anyone knows if this is just a bug with Microsoft DI? did my DI went too deep?

Or is there a workaround/fix for this?

I am really at a loss on why this is happening.

Update:
I tried to follow the suggestion to set the Common Language Exceptions, but it doesn't seem to be able to capture the data (I am very new so I might just be doing it wrong).

"Cannot obtain the value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away."

It is very odd that the StackOverflow exception is on the ThrowHelper.ThrowObjectDisposedException() line.  It means It is trying to GetService while the ServiceProviderEngine is already _disposed.  But I don't see why that would cause the Thrown Exception to StackOverflow.

Update (2021-08-31)

Added screenshot of the Call Stack. This is an Hanghfire that queues jobs to around 15 different APIs. Can too many (just sheer number) use up the stack? Sorry if this is an absurd question, I just started learning about DI when I was handed this project.

[image: Screenshot of the Call Stack]

Comment: There's not much we can do unless you show us the code that is calling this in the first place.

Comment: Debug > Windows > Exceptions, expand "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" and tick System.ObjectDisposedException.  Second time it hits you'll want to look at the stack trace to see how it got there.

Comment: It is DI so I have no idea which DI is causing it.  Because the code is not part of my own code, so I can't get much detail on it.   I can set the break but I can't seem to find any information.  I'll try what Hans said and see if I can get the stack trace.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @JamesX. Post the top of the call stack (until it repeats) from when you get the SO in the IDE.

Comment: It need not be the case that `ThrowObjectDisposedException` does anything wrong on its own. That call may just be the straw breaking the camel's back, with a more substantial and relevant stack trace of other calls clogging up the stack trace below it (or above it, as the case may be). It is even possible the stack is used up not by call frames but by local stack space allocated by enthusiastic functions (i.e. `Span<byte> b = stackalloc byte[1048576]` a few times), though that's unusual.

Comment: Although MS.DI has code to detect cyclic dependencies, my experience is that once you (or a used library) start using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`, all bets are off the table, and cyclic dependency detection goes out the window. That's likely because `ActivatorUtilities` is not integrated into MS.DI, but just calls back into the `IServiceProvider`. The problem with MS.DI, however, is that it is so limited in functionality that for almost any more-advanced wiring, you need `ActivatorUtilities`. Wiring decorators, for instance, typically requires ActivatorUtilities.

Comment: Although I agree with everyone here that you should post (part of) the stack trace, that stack trace will very likely be very generic in nature making it impossible to see where the problem lies. That stack trace will unlikely contain any information about the resolved classes. What we really need is a MRE, as @mjwills mentioned.

Comment: Added screenshot of the Call Stack.  This is an Hanghfire that queues jobs to around 15 different APIs.  Can too many (just sheer number) use up the stack? Sorry if this is an absurd question, I just started learning about DI when I was handed this project.

Comment: @JamesX. It seems like hangfire is trying to resolve some dependency during background job. So i would look at your jobs dependencies to see if maybe something is fishy there

Comment: I would put a breakpoint on that `_disposed = true` line and see what part of your application is causing the `ServiceProviderEngine` to be disposed in the first place.

Comment: I'm out of my depth (I don't know Hangfire), but this fits a scenario I've seen in the past where some background process was still running while the main logic was shutting down. Is this happening during shutdown? Is there something you can call on Hangfire to wait for pending tasks to complete?